# how to automate developers tools - console

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, qa-developer

How can we automate developer tools - console section using Selenium?
how to get data from the console for a particular service call.
ex: as per the screenshot attached I what to know *a.fn.init[div#804]*  call data using Java and Selenium in eclipse

Is it possible?
If so, how do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a.fn.init[div#804] call data"?

Comment: If anyone would have thought to look at your question instead of closing it based on the title (are we at stackoverflow here?) this would have been an answer but so let's do it in a comment. You can use the JavascriptExecutor class to make your function call. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return a.fn.init[div#804]") will call your function and give hand the return value back to your test script.